# NO LLEGA EL AUTHORIZATION A MI SPRING BOOT REST DESDE VUE.JS

Tags: api, vue.js, spring-boot, spring-security

Ando queriendo consumir mi api rest de Spirng en Vue.js pero nunca me llega el a mi api rest el JWT que le envio desde VUE.JS.

Tienen alguna idea porque se genera esto.

Aca les dejo mi codigo de java de spring boot:

```
public class AccountCredentials {

      private String username;
      private String password;
      // getters & setters
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
             ServletResponse response,
             FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {


      Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest)request);
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

      filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

  }
}

public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
    setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
      HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper()
        .readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            creds.getUsername(),
            ClavePass.Encriptar(creds.getPassword()),
            Collections.emptyList()
        )
    );
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(
      HttpServletRequest req,
      HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
      Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
    TokenAuthenticationService
        .addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
  }
}

class TokenAuthenticationService {
  static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
  static final String SECRET = "ThisIsASecret";
  static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";
  static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

  static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, String username) {
      String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)

                // Vamos a asignar un tiempo de expiracion de 1 minuto
                // solo con fines demostrativos en el video que hay al final
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000))

                // Hash con el que firmaremos la clave
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "nisira")
                .compact();

            //agregamos al encabezado el token
            res.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

  }

  static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
      String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
      // si hay un token presente, entonces lo validamos
      if (token != null) {
          String user = Jwts.parser()
                  .setSigningKey("P@tit0")
                  .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer", "")) //este metodo es el que valida
                  .getBody()
                  .getSubject();

          // Recordamos que para las demás peticiones que no sean /login
          // no requerimos una autenticacion por username/password 
          // por este motivo podemos devolver un UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken sin password
          return user != null ?
                  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList()) :
                  null;
      }
      return null;
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private IUsuarioService usuarioService;
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
//        // We filter the api/login requests
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Create a default account
    Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findAll().stream().filter(U -> U.getIdusuario().trim().equals("ADMINISTRADOR")).findFirst().orElse(null);
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser(usuario.getIdusuario().trim())
      .password(usuario.getPassword())
      .roles("ADMIN");
  }
}
```

Este es mi codigo de Vue.js con el que consumo esa api:

```
this.axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/teatro', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'hola' 
      }
      })
```

Cuando llega al metodo :

```
@Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
      HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
```

> AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper()

```
    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        creds.getUsername(),
        ClavePass.Encriptar(creds.getPassword()),
        Collections.emptyList()
    )
);
```

}

Busco si llega el JWT, nunca llega pero cuando lo mando desde postman si, nose si se tiene que agregar algo mas al spring boot o al vue.js para que le pueda llegar los parametros.

Comment: Me falta algún detalle, pero tiene toda la pinta de ser un problema con CORS: ¿está tu front-end en un servidor distinto, con otro puerto?

Comment: esta en mi local corriendo en otro puerto.

Comment: Pues seguramente es un problema de CORS

Comment: No content to map due to end-of-input este error me sale ahora